# Multiple Selection From Dropdown Using if-else Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create two dropdowns based on user input. If a user selects "val1", then show values in the second dropdown from "x". If "val2", then "y". If both "val1" and "val2", then z.

So far, I succeeded except for the multiple selection part. I also tried:

`else if (input$lab == "val1" & input$lab == "val2")`

which gives me the same error:

`the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

```
x <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
y <- c("y1", "y2", "y3")
z <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y1", "y2", "y3")
```

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("xxx", tabName = "tab1")
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",
        pickerInput("dropdown1", "Values:", choices = c("x", "y"), multiple = T),
        uiOutput("dropdown2")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactive({
    req(input$dropdown1)
    
    if (input$dropdown1 == "x") {
      x
    }
    
    else if (input$dropdown1 == "y") {
      y
    }
    
    else if (input$dropdown1 == "x" && input$dropdown1 == "y") {
      z
    }
  })
  
  output$dropdown2 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput("dropdown2", "Values:", choices = values())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does it work to just specify the last part of your if/else as an else - that is, if "val1", x, else if "val2", y, else z? Without seeing how your app is structured it's hard to test solutions.

Comment: I just added a fully working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight change in approach in your server. Rather than ifelse to test for for x, y, or x&y, you can instead test for length == 1 and then within that case, whether it's x or y.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactive({
    req(input$dropdown1)
    
    if (length(input$dropdown1) == 1) {
      if (input$dropdown1 == "x") {
        c("x1", "x2", "x3")
      }
      else {
        c("y1", "y2", "y3")
      }
    }
    else {
      c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y1", "y2", "y3")
    }
  })
  
  output$dropdown2 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput("dropdown2", "Values:", choices = values())
  })
  
}
```

Depending on what really will go in "x" and "y", using `ifelse()` might save you space in this approach.